# Linq select to injected object with Valueinjecter

Tags: dictionary, valueinjecter

Can I convert a IQueryable result to a injected object on the fly?

I know I can do this with the help of Valueinjecter:

```
usercategory uc1 = new usercategory(example);
usercategoryViewData ucVD1 = new usercategoryViewData();
ucVD1.injectFrom(uc1);
```

So instead of this:

```
from u in db.usercategories
where u.id==id
select new usercategoryViewModel {id = u.id, name = u.id, description = u.id};
```

I would like to use something like:

```
from u in db.usercategories
where u.id==id
select new usercategoryViewModel.InjectFrom(u);
```

The other alternative I have atm is to loop through a IEnumerable and create one with injected objects instead.

Comment: do you want something like foos.Select(o => new Bar().InjectFrom(o)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here I show 2 ways of doing this:

```
        public class Foo
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }            
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var bars = new[] { new { Name = "aaa" }, new { Name = "bbb" } };
            IEnumerable<Foo> foos = bars.Select(o => new Foo().InjectFrom(o)).Cast<Foo>();

            IEnumerable<Foo> foos2 = from bar in bars
                        select new Foo().InjectFrom(bar) as Foo;

            Assert.AreEqual(bars.First().Name, foos.First().Name);
            Assert.AreEqual(bars.First().Name, foos2.First().Name);
        }
```

Comment: How about joining/combining multiple result sets into 1 collection? Thanks.

Comment: @ChuckNorris - Please see my question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143241/valueinjecter-joins-multiple-result-sets-into-1-collection-linq here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst that might be possible, if there's any complexity in `u` then I think it's a bad idea.

At some point the ORM you're using (Linq-to-SQL? EF?) needs to switch from executing on the database to executing in .NET. At that boundary it needs to work out what data it needs from the database. In the first example, that's completely clear: it only needs `u.id`. In the second it has no idea: it doesn't know what properties `InjectFrom` will read from it, so it will need to load all the values from the UserCategories table, and maybe related objects too, just in case.

Comment: Yes, but I want a simple / default map between equally named properties. A standard task for the mapper function. For more complexity I would need assigning a LoopValueInjection-class.