# ValueInjecter - Joins multiple result sets into 1 collection LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, valueinjecter

How do I use ValueInjecter with a LINQ join that joins multiple result sets? For example, this code inject `result` values into `CombinedResult` object, but I also want some of `errorsAndWarning` values into `CombinedResult`. The properties have the same name:

```
var combined = from result in results.DeferredItems
               join errorsAndWarning in errorsAndWarnings.DeferredItems
                on result.MeetingID equals errorsAndWarning.MeetingID
               select new CombinedResult().InjectFrom(result) as CombinedResult;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
var combined = from result in results.DeferredItems
               join errorsAndWarning in errorsAndWarnings.DeferredItems
                on result.MeetingID equals errorsAndWarning.MeetingID
               select new CombinedResult().InjectFrom(result)
                                          .InjectFrom(errorsAndWarning)
                                          as CombinedResult;
```

Comment: hey , daniel , why does this not works with IQueryable data source ? is there a way to inner join two tables and mapping to a viewmodel ? thx

Comment: @dfang: "Doesn't work" isn't an error description. What is the problem with your code?

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object InjectFrom(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." 
see my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988573 , thx !